# Setting up NSPredicate with a phrase and number sequence

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I'm sorry if this is an overly specific question. Tried searching for basic help with NSPredicate and getting nowhere.

I'm trying to validate a string that should begin with a particular word (let's say it's SPOT, in all caps) and is followed by exactly 4 numeric digits.

In other words, for example, SPOT1234 or SPOT0483 would pass validation. SPAT1234, spot1234, SPOT123 or any other string would fail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: NSRegularExpression?

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [NSPredicate with a regular expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9).

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"SPOT1234", @"SPOT0483", @"SPAT1234", @"spot1234", @"SPOT123", @"SPOT1233232"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^SPOT\\\\d{4}$'"];
NSArray *resultsArray = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The resultsArray will contain two strings: SPOT1234, SPOT0483

Comment: Great, this regex is correct. To turn it into a validity check, rather than an array filter, I used this:

- (BOOL)validateCodeWithString:(NSString*)code {
    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^SPOT\\\\d{4}$'"];
    return [test evaluateWithObject:code];
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` as @Larme said like this:

```
- (BOOL)validateString:(NSString *)string {
    return [string rangeOfString:@"^SPOT\\d{4}$" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound;
}

NSLog(@"%d", [self validateString:@"SPOT123456789"]);  // false
NSLog(@"%d", [self validateString:@"SPAT1234"]);       // false
NSLog(@"%d", [self validateString:@"spot1234"]);       // false
NSLog(@"%d", [self validateString:@"SPOT123"]);        // false
NSLog(@"%d", [self validateString:@"SPOT0483"]);       // true
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Any string that starts with SPOT and ends with any four digits should pass. (Not just the two examples I gave)

Comment: The string must eight digit? "SPOTxxxx1234" pass or not?

Comment: SPOTxxxx1234 should fail. The string must have a total of 8 characters. The first 4 should be exactly "SPOT". The last 4 should be any numeric digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSArray *arrStr = @[@"SPOT1212",@"spot1234",@"SPOT12233"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self LIKE \"SPOT????\""]];
NSArray *filterArr = [arrStr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```